# preg replace functions and http://?

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to change this `array` for `preg_replace`.

```
// URLS
$pattern[1] = '/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i';
$replace[1] = "<a href=\"http://$1\">$2</a>";
// IMAGES
$pattern[2] = '/\[img\=(.*?)\]/i';
$replace[2] = "<img src=\"http://$1\" alt=\"\" />";
```

So the if a user includes the `http://` it will not add it, and if the user doesn't add the `http://` it will add it.

Currently it only works if a user disregards the `http://`

Thanks

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `(http://)?`.

```
$pattern[1] = '~\[url\=(http://)?(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]~i';
$replace[1] = "<a href=\"http://$2\">$2</a>";

$pattern[2] = '~\[img\=(http://)?(.*?)\]~i';
$replace[2] = "<img src=\"http://$2\" alt=\"\" />";
```

BTW, why not **use a character as a delimiter that is not in the pattern already**? Like I used `~` here.

Comment: Will try this now :) I just fixed it with using this after the preg_replace `$input = str_replace('http://http://', 'http://', $input);` but it isn't very pretty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// URLS
$pattern[1] = '/\[url\=([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*):(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i';
$replace[1] = "<a href=\"$1:$2\">$3</a>";
// IMAGES
$pattern[2] = '/\[img\=([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*):(.*?)\]/i';
$replace[2] = "<img src=\"$1:$2\" alt=\"\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace for this, match `/^(?!http:\/\/)/` and replace occurences with "http://".

Comment: Just add it as another section of the array?